# PHP search engine isn't matching to specific term in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-app-engine

I have a simple search engine running on my website, but every time I search for a very specific term like "june 7" it shows everything related to "june" in the database. I can't figure out how to get my PHP search engine to call on a specific keyword from the database.. Help???

Here is my code..

```
    <?PHP
    function getmicrotime()
    {
 list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
 }
 //initializing connection to the database 
 $connection_string = dirname(__FILE__) . "/connectionstring.php";
 require_once($connection_string);
 //selecting table
  mysql_select_db("jaguartr_logins") or die ( 'Unable to select database.' );
 //max number of results on the page
 $RESULTS_LIMIT=1000;
 if(isset($_GET['search_term']) && isset($_GET['search_button']))
 {
   $search_term = $_GET['search_term'];
if(!isset($first_pos))
{
    $first_pos = "0";
}

$start_search = getmicrotime();

// initializing MySQL query  
$sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE MATCH(title,article) AGAINST('$search_term')");

// additional check. Insurance method to re-search the database again in case of too many matches (too many matches cause returning of 0 results)
if($results = mysql_num_rows($sql_query) != 0)
{
    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM news WHERE MATCH(title,article) AGAINST('$search_term') LIMIT $first_pos, $RESULTS_LIMIT";
    $sql_result_query = mysql_query($sql);         
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE (title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_term)."%' OR article LIKE '%".$search_term."%') ";
    $sql_query = mysql_query($sql);
    $results = mysql_num_rows($sql_query);

    $sql_result_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE (title LIKE '%".$search_term."%' OR article LIKE '%".$search_term."%') LIMIT $first_pos, $RESULTS_LIMIT ");
}

$stop_search = getmicrotime();

//calculating the search time
$time_search = ($stop_search - $start_search);
}
?>

<?PHP
   if($results != 0)
   {
?>
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue with longer search terms? I mean, 7 is just one character short and could be ignored. Try something longer.

Comment: Yes, if I type in "June 7" in the search bar, it pulls anything within the database that starts with "J"

Answer (score 0):

To search for a particular string value within a character column, you can use `LIKE` condition

```
 WHERE mycol LIKE '%june 7%'
```

If you want to make use of a full-text index, you could use a boolean search and use double quotes to indicate a match to an exact phrase

```
 WHERE MATCH (mycol) AGAINST ('+"june 7"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But I'm expecting the full text search isn't going to return any results, because the token "`7`" is shorter than the minimum token length. (Either `innodb_ft_min_token_size` or `ft_min_word_len`, depending on whether the table is InnoDB or MyISAM).

This is an issue with MySQL. If you can't get a MySQL query to do the search you need, then you'll likely need a different search engine. The PHP code would need to be semi-aware of what the MySQL search limitations are, and create the appropriate SQL to perform the search, based on the particular words or phrases.

Comment: I need the %search_term% to be an exact match with what's in the database. I'm not performing a query within MySQL, I'm just wanting to retrieve an exact match from the database with my php.